# Generate macOS-like password in terminal using bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I want to generate a password that would follow the pattern of passwords Apple prompts during account creation.

A password string pattern will look like this `xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx`. Where one `x` is a number and one `x` is a capital letter. **Hyphens also need to be included.**

The result may look like this: `abcdef-ghijk3-mnoPqr` - where `3` is a number and `P` is a capital letter.

Valid outputs are:

- `abcdef-ghijk1-mnoPqr` (`1` and `P`)
- `abcd3F-ghijkl-mnopqr` (`3` and `F`)
- `abcdef-Ghijkl-mn0pqr` (`G` and `0`)
- `abcdef-nhijk1-mnqrX` (`1` and `X`)

Invalid outputs are:

- `aBCD3f-Nh1jk1-Mn0qr`
- `AbcDwF-gH1jJl-mn0FqR`

How can I do it using typical bash commands `sed` or `awk` and similar?

Comment: I do not understand the password pattern. Is `ABCDEF-GHIJK1-MNOPQR` also valid? Is `XXXXXX-XXXXXX-111111` valid? It'd help if you could provide a matching regex.

Comment: You'll have to be careful generating passwords with a "typical" random number generator: [What does it mean for a random number generator to be cryptographically secure?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/39186/what-does-it-mean-for-a-random-number-generator-to-be-cryptographically-secure)

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you are having problems with. Do you have existing code that can create any kind of random password? If yes, show the code. If not, is this the main point of your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `openssl` I used `/dev/urandom`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

makepasswd() {
    (   chars=$(LC_ALL=C tr -dc a-zA-Z0-9 </dev/urandom | head -c 2000 ; echo '')
        tr -cd '0-9' <<<"$chars" | head -c 1
        tr -cd 'A-Z' <<<"$chars" | head -c 1
        tr -cd 'a-z' <<<"$chars" | head -c 16
    ) | sed 's/./&\n/g' \
      | shuf \
      | paste -d'\0' - - - - - - \
      | paste -d'-' - - -
}

for in in {1..5}; do makepasswd; done
```

Is it a better idea to make it more robust across platforms?

Answer (score 1):

notwithstanding my warning comment, with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and [shuf](/questions/tagged/shuf)

```bash
rndchar() {
    local i=$(( 1 + RANDOM % $# ))
    echo "${!i}"
}

makepasswd() {
    local chars=()
    for i in {1..16}; do chars+=("$(rndchar {a..z})"); done
    chars+=("$(rndchar {A..Z})")
    chars+=("$(rndchar {0..9})")

    mapfile -t chars < <(printf '%s\n' "${chars[@]}" | shuf)

    local IFS=
    printf '%s-%s-%s\n' "${chars[*]:0:6}" "${chars[*]:6:6}" "${chars[*]:12:6}"
}
```

then

```bash
$ for in in {1..5}; do makepasswd; done
qek5qo-Mfwtqm-ujwrni
zkcfjd-gDgleh-zklhk2
Qureng-alsyus-y8nbvp
lbkusw-fSkqua-ghws4x
uKope4-vrzeqm-iwidgw
```

---

With pipelines of tools: requires [openssl](/questions/tagged/openssl) as the random character generator

```bash
makepasswd() {
    (   chars=$(openssl rand -base64 1024)
        tr -cd '0-9' <<<"$chars" | head -c 1
        tr -cd 'A-Z' <<<"$chars" | head -c 1
        tr -cd 'a-z' <<<"$chars" | head -c 16
    ) | sed 's/./&\n/g' \
      | shuf \
      | paste -d '' - - - - - - \
      | paste -d '-' - - -
}
```

```bash
$ for in in {1..5}; do makepasswd; done
aubbbm-qelNvl-0mbhbf
zyqvon-oqifkv-fkbgW2
wtzqpo-yl0mce-xaquhQ
xljzp8-xdfoeW-wxokxf
cqydyt-f6mwmn-vqLkce
```

Comment: That's correct! But can it be achieved using more common text parsing methods?